# Declaration of ... should be compatible with ... - overwrite parent method completely?

Tags: php, inheritance, php-5.5

I get this error `Strict standards: Declaration of Boo::sayHello() should be compatible with Foo::sayHello($param = false) in C:\...`

Because I don't set `$param = false` or `true` in the extended child class.

```
class Foo
{
    var $message = 'Hello Foo';

    public function sayHello($param = false)
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}

class Boo extends Foo
{
    public function sayHello($param)
    {
        return 'Hello Boo';
    }

    public function sayWorld($b)
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}

$boo = new Boo;
var_dump($boo->sayHello('a'));
var_dump($boo->sayWorld('b'));
```

Is it possible to **overwrite completely** or **redefine** the method in the parent class?

By the way, is it a **bad** practice by doing so?

Comment: It is. You declare that `Boo` **is a** `Foo`, then you tell it's not.

Comment: You can't strengthen a method signature in child classes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that the number of parameters on `Boo::sayHello()` does not match the parent `Foo::sayHello()`, by having a default of `$param=false` on `Foo::sayHello()` this function can be called with no parameters where as the child class function `Boo::sayHello()` requires a parameter.

Consider the following function:

```
function baz (Foo $f) { $f->sayHello(); }
```

The compiler only checks the correctness of this function call against `Foo::sayHello()` as any objects of sub-type `Foo` should have the same method signature for `sayHello()`.

If you passed an object of `Boo` to the above function this would not work as expected due to the difference in method signatures/required parameters.

You should be able to pass child class objects in place of parent objects - by redefining parent functions with different signatures you are going against this and may result in runtime errors.